# RazorEngine v3 Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, razorengine

I need to write a custom base template which needs to have a constructor parameter injected.

For RazorEngine v2 [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130523121045/http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=276) illustrates very clearly how has to be done.

How should custom base template DI be done in v3? I mean is there still a way to express activator through `Func<>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is still very possible, the method by which you configure your template service has changed as I wanted to centralise all configuration into one interface. The following url (https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/blob/release-3.0/src/Core/Tests/RazorEngine.Core.Tests/ActivatorTestFixture.cs) is an example of a unit test I've built that demonstrates using DI with Unity, this one specifically is using an activator.

A `DelegateActivator` does exist in the `RazorEngine.Templating` namespace that will allow you to achieve what you want. I'm looking at ways at trying to simplifying this. You could also configure it using the Fluent configuration API:

```
var config = new FluentTemplateServiceConfiguration(c =>
    c.ActivateUsing(context => {your code here}));

var service = new TemplateService(config);
```